# Visual Studio 2010 Extension - Cannot break execution in Experimental Instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to break execution with Debug points in a Visual Studio extension running against a Visual Studio 2010 Experimental Instance.

For some reason, when trying to break execution, I receive an error:

```
"Unable to break execution.  This process is not currently executing the type of code that you selected to debug."
```

Oddly enough, I can debug without any problem in a Visual Studio 2005, and 2008 Experimental Instance.

Has anyone else ran into this with VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-installed Visual Studio 2010 and the SDK.  This seemed to work at first, but after changing a source file and launching the Debugger, I was unable to break execution yet again.

I went to Tools->Options and unchecked '*Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run*'.  This fixed it!  This must have something to do with an extension solution that supports both VS2008 and VS2010.

Comment: I had this problem when my project targeted an early version of the framework than the executable being debugged.

Comment: A small clarification: the option Sheldon mentioned is found in Tools -> Options, Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the problem is that you're setup to debug only managed code in your VS 2010 project file.  If you're setup to debug only managed you'll get this message if VS is currently executing native code (VS spends a good portion of it's time in native code).

To fix this do the following

- Right Click on the project and select Properties
- Go to the Debug Tab
- Check "Enable unmanaged code debugging"

Comment: When I do this, I get an error "Debugging information for 'devenv.exe' cannot be found or does not match.  Cannot find or open the PDF file.  Do you want to continue debugging?'  Maybe my SDK install for 2010 has a problem?

Comment: @SheldonWarkentin that's expected. I would just hit ignore.  It's basically complaining that you don't have a PDB for devenv.exe.  Microsoft may offer it on their public symbol server but it's not necessary for actually debugging your code

Comment: Yeah, I would figure there are no debug symbols for devenv.exe.  After this message, however, I still cannot seem to break execution in the VS 2010 instance.

Comment: @SheldonWarkentin that's **really** strange. If you are debugging managed + native then stop should always work.  Have you disabled "Just My Code"?  If not try doing so (Tools -> Options -> Debugger and unchkce "Enable Just my Code Debugging")

Comment: thank you for trying to help me figure this out.  I'm just not having any luck.  I am going to try to reinstall the VS2010 SDK next week and see if that helps.